# Minimal and maximal number of components in a union of two graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Union of graphs $G(V_1, E_1)$ and  $G(V_2, E_2)$ is defined and denoted by 
$ G(V_1, E_1)\cup  G(V_2, E_2)=G(V_1\cup V_2, E_1\cup E_2)$.

> Suppose, $G_1$ with $m$ vertices and $G_2$ with $n$ vertices are two arbitrary simple graphs with $p$ and $q$ components, respectively. Also, $G_1$ and $G_2$ have $e$ edges in common. What is the maximal and the minimal number of components in $G(V_1, E_1)\cup  G(V_2, E_2)$?

Comment: The question is not well defined. Did you mean to ask what is the minimal/maximal number of components in $G(V_1, E_1)\cup  G(V_2, E_2)$?

Comment: @TheHoly joker question is edited accordingly. Thanks

Comment: are $V_1,V_2$  disjoint? or do we know anything about them? they obviously can't be disjoint, but I think I'm missing something if $V_1\neq V_2$

Comment: @TheHoly Joker $G(V_1, E_1)$ and $G(V_2, E_2)$ have $e$ edges in common just to mean that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are not disjoint. And nothing else is known about the relationship between $V_1$ and $V_2$. I think this is a hard problem.

Comment: I'm probably completely wrong, but I think it is easy to construct two examples in which the number of CC of the union is the sum of the number of CC, which is also equal to $n+m$ (for the lower upper bound), and another one, in which the number of CC is the min between the number of CC of each graph.

Comment: @ Theholy Joker.  You may post it as answer with detailed explanations.